# "June 8 2023, 02:00 pm" change to "8 June 2023, 14:00"

Tags: html, django, windows, django-models, debian

please help me figure this out. I made a project on django on Windows OS, transferred it to debian server, everything works, but there is a problem with displaying the date: I use `updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`, on Windows OS it is displayed as: `8 June 2023, 14:00`, but on debian for some reason it is displayed as: `June 8 2023, 02:00 pm`. What could be the problem? How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add `|date:"j F Y, G:i"`

before: `{{ updated_at }}`

after: `{{ updated_at|date:"j E Y, G:i" }}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date